# Adding a checkbox next to each list item using a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a todo list using javascript and this is what I've got so far:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id='TodoTable-wrapper'>
    <ul id='TodoTable'>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder= "What needs to be done?" id="todoText">
<button class="btn" id="addTodo">Add</button>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 var inputField = document.getElementById('todoText');
 var todoList = new Array();
 var uList = document.getElementById('TodoTable');
 var addButton = document.getElementById('addTodo');

 var listItemCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
 listItemCheckbox.type = 'checkbox';

 var addTodo = function (todoText) {
addToArray(todoText);
refreshList();
   };

var addToArray = function(text) {
todoList.push(inputField.value);
}



var refreshList = function() {
uList.innerHTML = "";
var listItem;
for (var i = 0; i<todoList.length; i++) {
    listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.innerHTML = todoList[i];
    uList.appendChild(listItem);
    listItem.appendChild(listItemCheckbox);
}
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
var todoText = inputField.value;
addTodo(todoText);
});
```

The problem I have is that as a new list item is created, only the last item in the list has a checkbox next to it (the previews ones get deleted). I have an inkling that this happens because the function refreshList creates a new list every time the array 'todoList' is updated and the 'listItem.appendChild' only runs once in the for loop.

Is there a way for me to get it run every time a list item is created, as well as find a way to associate it with the corresponding list item? (so I can create a function to delete individual list items later).

Thanks alot in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reusing the same checkbox object.
You should create a new checkbox everytime you need to add one, otherwise you are just moving it from one place to another.

Comment: thanks, that made sense. I've moved the /* var listItemCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
  listItemCheckbox.type = 'checkbox'; */ into the loop and it works now :)